# is it possible to cache some selected views in ionic before enter to them?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a couple of views that are a little heavy, I would like to cache them before the user see go into one.

Is there a way to do this? I can't find information about it.

Answer (score 0):

Ionic already does this for you:

> By default, views are cached to improve 
>   performance. When a view is navigated away from, its element is left
>   in the DOM, and its scope is disconnected from the $watch cycle. When
>   navigating to a view that is already cached, its scope is then
>   reconnected, and the existing element that was left in the DOM becomes
>   the active view. This also allows for the scroll position of previous
>   views to be maintained.
>
> Caching can be disabled and enabled in multiple ways. By default,
>   Ionic will cache a maximum of 10 views, and not only can this be
>   configured, but apps can also explicitly state which views should and
>   should not be cached.

Take a look at their documention for ionNavView [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavView/) which goes over in more detail about caching views, as well as [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionView/) for ionView (the child view of ionNavView). You can use `cache-view` Boolean to set whether the view should be cached or not before entering.  In your state provider you would set the cache to false:

```
$stateProvider.state('myState', {
cache: false,
url : '/myUrl',
templateUrl : 'my-template.html'
})
```

And to change the number cached by default set it in your configure:

```
$ionicConfigProvider.views.maxCache(0);
```

Hope this helps.

EDIT:

If you want to cache some views at the start of the app then you can do so as well. As I mentioned by default Ionic caches views for you, but only until you enter it for the first time. **Angular TemplateCache** can make sure all/or some views are already cached at app startup. So no more initial lag when entering *hefty* views for the first time as you mentioned.

Checkout the documentation for it [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache), and an example of it [here](http://tombuyse.com/improving-the-performance-of-your-ionic-application/).

Comment: I mean cache it **before** the user goes into. For example, I have a `HomePage` and `Page1`, `Page2`. The first time I go from `HomePage` to `Page1` I *see* how it gets loaded, if later I go back to `Page1` It is faster because it was cached after I left it. I want to be able to cached without the need to go first.

Comment: Ah ok, I edited my answer, you can cache views before entering as well.